# Is it possible to run art(android runtime) binaries in other arm linuxes?

Tags: android, linux, arm, package, runtime

If android runtime compiles the .dex file into arm executable .elf file and several other .so shared object library then in which directory these compiled files are stored? 
Is it possible run those .elf executable in other arm linux systems by copy the compiled .elf and .so file from android and placing them equivalent path of where they were?
Is it possible to add art (android runtime) to other arm linuxes as within a apk package manager or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible run those .elf executable in other arm linux systems by copy the compiled .elf and .so file from android and placing them equivalent path of where they were?

No. There is more to running a program than what is contained within the program's binaries. AFAIK, that is true for every operating system ever written; it is certainly true for the major modern operating systems.

> Is it possible to add art (android runtime) to other arm linuxes as within a apk package manager or something like that?

No.